# How to use properties declared as Function

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer has the type *Function* for its properties (see doc [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties)). Do you have any example of its use? Is it possible to pass such function within the html attribute of the tag (e.g., `<tagcomponent myfunc="xyz">`)?

I created a polymer components [polywc-data-source-rest](https://github.com/donpir/polywc-data-table/blob/e6b4581dd2836a3cfdfb85e09753a84fae698228/polywc-data-source-rest.html) to access a restful service using pagination. It has properties to specify the maximum items per page, the page or item offset as in the following snippet of code.

```
<polywc-data-table>
<polywc-data-source-rest id="ds"
            base-url="https://data.dublinked.ie/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=c0ad65f7-6000-4e0d-b972-275cf76d288b"
            items-per-page-key="limit" item-offset-key="offset" 
            post-process-data="fncPostProcessData">
</polywc-data-source-rest>
</polywc-data-table>
```

The problem is that the retrieved JSON must be post-processed, and only the users knows what to do because it heavily depends on the JSON. My idea is to have a property named postProcessData, which is the function to post process data. An incomplete example of its use is [Here](https://github.com/donpir/polywc-data-table/blob/e6b4581dd2836a3cfdfb85e09753a84fae698228/demo/index-rest.html). Is this the correct way to design it or I'm missing something?

Comment: I believe you've misread the docs. There is no `Function` property type. The possible values for the `type` field are: `Type: constructor (one of Boolean, Date, Number, String, Array or Object)`. You probably saw `Type: boolean, number, string or function.`, which actually applies to the `value` field.

Comment: fyi, I've filed a [style bug](https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/1626) in Polymer/docs regarding this.

Comment: Yes, it is difficult to discern cells within the polymer documentation! Indeed, the "function" is for the value. What also misled me, is that within the polymer source code it seems that they use it [Here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/edb59eb6283074ce54f374b30b884c9f9fcf9f5f/src/lib/template/dom-repeat.html); there is sort: { type: Function, ... }.

Comment: Oh, interesting... My experiments show that the `type` field actually accepts any symbol, as seen in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qaraca/edit?html,console). Although, I'd hesitate to use an undocumented "feature".